# How to config custom URL of Laravel-stapler

Tags: php, laravel-4

I use Laravel4 with Laravel-stapler to manipulate images.

I am designing the product catalog on web, there are two table.

1. Table "Product" has the information about product, such as, product name, product size, product description and **a product highlight image**.
2. Table "Product_Gallery" has the unlimit images of product.

And, I set the model as below,

```
class Products extends Eloquent implements StaplerableInterface {
     public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {
        $this->hasAttachedFile('product_main_image', [
                'styles' => [
                        'thumb' => ['dimensions' => '100x100#' ],                       
                        'display' => ['dimensions' => '300x300#' ],

                ],
                'url' => '/uploads/product/:id/:style/:filename',                   
        ]);
...


class ProductGallery extends Eloquent implements StaplerableInterface {
     public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {
        $this->hasAttachedFile('product_gallery', [
                'styles' => [
                        'thumb' => ['dimensions' => '100x100#' ],                       
                        'gallery' => ['dimensions' => '1024x' ],

                ],
                'url' => '/uploads/gallery/:id/:style/:filename',                   
        ]);
...
```

When I upload a product and  with four gallery files, they storage as below,

```
/uploads/product/1/thumb/aaaa.jpg
/uploads/gallery/1/thumb/g1.jpg
/uploads/gallery/2/thumb/g2.jpg
/uploads/gallery/3/thumb/g3.jpg
/uploads/gallery/4/thumb/g4.jpg
```

I would like to group the file upload of product gallery into product folder, for example,

```
/uploads/product/1/thumb/aaaa.jpg
/uploads/product/1/gallery/1/thumb/g1.jpg
/uploads/product/1/gallery/2/thumb/g2.jpg
/uploads/product/1/gallery/3/thumb/g3.jpg
/uploads/product/1/gallery/4/thumb/g4.jpg
```

This code in Controller,

```
    $model = new ProductGallery();
    $model->fk_id = $product_id;
    $model->image = Input::file('file');
    $pathInfo = pathinfo(Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName());
    $newFilename =  'gallery-' . date("Ymd-") . sha1(time()) . '.' . $pathInfo['extension'];
    $model->image->instanceWrite('file_name', $newFilename);        
    $model->save();
```

***How to config the Laravel-stapler?***

Comment: Please provide your controller code where you upload attachment.

Comment: @ArkarAung I already add controller code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Laravel-stapler](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/laravel-stapler), there is no built-in interpolations for that yet. But you can achieve this by passing product id via constructor of your model. 
Try this ..

In your controller,

```
$model = new ProductGallery(array("product_id" => $product_id));
$model->fk_id = $product_id;
$model->image = Input::file('file');
$pathInfo = pathinfo(Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName());
$newFilename =  'gallery-' . date("Ymd-") . sha1(time()) . '.' . $pathInfo['extension'];
$model->image->instanceWrite('file_name', $newFilename);        
$model->save();
```

In your model,

```
class ProductGallery extends Eloquent implements StaplerableInterface {
     public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {
        $this->hasAttachedFile('product_gallery', [
                'styles' => [
                        'thumb' => ['dimensions' => '100x100#' ],                       
                        'gallery' => ['dimensions' => '1024x' ],

                ],
                'url' => '/uploads/product/'.$attributes['product_id'].'/gallery/:id/:style/:filename',                   
        ]);
...
```

Hope it will be useful for you.